# PHP 5.4 basic login script

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Trying to learn myself PHP with some database interaction and I am trying to do a "simple" (most things can be relative...) login script and when I first tried it I got a few errors about session_register which I now understand is deprecated and I tried to change it to $_SESSION['something'] = 'something';

My database is set with a user, I can connect fine and pick the right database but when I enter the username and password I get sen back to the login form, which it should do when it fails.

I do have something to catch wrong username or password that got casted when I used the deprecated version. I just have three filed, main_login.php, checklogin.php and login_success.php and will post them below.

main_login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='application/xhtml+xml; charset=UTF-8' />

    <title>Login</title>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- CSS FILES -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/default.css' />
</head>
<body>
    <div id='wrapper'>
        <div id='loginform'>
            <form action="checklogin.php" method='post' id='login'>
                Username: <br />
                <input type='text' name='username' /><br />
                Password: <br />
                <input type='text' name='password' /><br />
                <input type='submit' value='Login' />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

checklogin.php

```
<?PHP
//Server/database settings
ob_start();
$host       = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "";
$db_name    = "user";
$tbl_name   = "userdata";

//Connect to the server and select the database
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password") or die ("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ("cannot select DB");

//Get the username and password from the login form
//Prevent SQL injections
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST['password']));
$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
//$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
//$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username = '$username'
and password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

//Count the table row. 0 = No user exists
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

//If $result is 1 the user exists
if($count == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
    $_SESSION['password'] = '$password';
    header('location:login_success.php');
}

/*  //If the result match the $username && $password, table row will be 1
if($count == 1) {
    session_register('username');
    session_register('password');
    header('location:login_success.php');
}*/

//If it does not match, give a return message
else {
    echo 'Wrong Username or Password';
}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

and the last login_success.php

```
<?PHP
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:main_login.php');
}
?>
<html>
    <body>
        Login Successful
    </body>
</html>
```

This just throws me back to the login page :/

Also if anyone notice any code that can be vulnerable to SQL injection, feel free to point that out and suggest what I should do instead.

Comment: Why the downvote? Did I not ask a relevant question to the forum or did I pick the wrong tags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Remove the quotes:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
$_SESSION['password'] = '$password';
```

#### Replace with:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

---

#### Replace

```
ob_start();
```

#### With:

```
session_start();
ob_start();
```

---

#### Why did you remove this?

```
//$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
//$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
```

It is very much required, else your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: I removed it because I added it a few lines above directly with $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);, was that wrong, I need to have them both?

Comment: @Angel No, it is right. Fine. :)

Answer (score 2):

Well, I don't see a `session_start()` call in the checklogin.php

And your code indeed vulnerable to injection, because for some reason you are stripping the very escaping you applied a line before. Why this `stripslashes()` call?

Also, keep in mind that `mysql_real_escape_string()` does not prevent injections by itself.
Only properly formatted data can guarantee you from injection and there are nearly dozen formatting rules, not one.
Though as long as you are adding only quoted strings into query, and pass every one of them strings through `mysql_real_escape_string()`, your query is perfectly safe.

Comment: I have it there if I wanted to output a quoted string but might not be needed here, just playing around a bit. Thx for the feedback on the SQL, still really new to it and will remember your advice on quotes.

Comment: What do you mean with "stripping the very escaping I applied"? You saying that using the stripslashes() call makes it more vulnerable to injection?

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;
```

and as [Your Common Sense](https://stackoverflow.com/users/285587/your-common-sense) said please add `session_start()` in beginning of `checklogin.php`.